# Time Series Prediction | Training the Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

So I loaded and preprocessed my data for time-series prediction. I've created a model, but now I am not sure how to actually train it.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

# Loading Data
df = pd.read_csv("testdata.csv", header=0, parse_dates=[
                 0], names=['Month', 'People'], index_col=0)

print(df)
print(df.shape)

# Preprocessing
log_df_People = np.log(df.People)
print(log_df_People)
log_df_People_diff = log_df_People - log_df_People.shift()
print(log_df_People_diff)
log_df_People_diff.dropna(inplace=True)

# Creating the Model
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation="relu", input_shape=(2,))
model.add = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)
model.add = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Training the Model?
```

I did some research, but there isn't exactly an in depth tutorial on how to specifically train a model for time-series prediction.

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression maybe it is what you are looking for. I would write a code sample but i think it would be better for you to discover the solution on your own.

Comment: Do you want to use the people value of the current and the previous month to predict the value of the next month? the input and the desired output are not clear in your question

Comment: @Meto I am trying to do Time-Series Prediction though.

Comment: @HusseinAwala Sorry about that, I want to use the value of next month to predict people value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear how your dataframe looks like and why you log it. But here I will show you how you can use `LSTM` to train a model for prediction. 
Let's imagine the following is your data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'People':[10,12,11,13,15,18]})
```

Then you do `log` for some reason:

```
log_df_People = np.log(df.People)
```

Then you shift like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
X = log_df_People.to_numpy()[:-1]
Y = log_df_People.shift(-1).to_numpy()[:-1]
```

Then you create your model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, activation="relu", input_shape=(2,))
model.add = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)
model.add = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_absolute_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Finally you train your model for a number of epochs:

```
model.fit(X,Y,epochs=100)
```

But generally you should think about using sliding windows to make predictions, but this would require much more description.

Comment: Nice and clear explanation! As you also mentioned using a sliding window approach, would you be kind to shine some light on it with a basic example or perhaps referencing some useful coding sources? Thank you!

Comment: @Jack_T, you can read my paper "Anomaly Detection in Univariate Time-series: A Survey on the State-of-the-Art" (https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.00433). There the sliding window approach is explained in detail.